# Draw a line given an equation in a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, perceptron

I have some data points and I plotted the scatter plot using matplotlib. Now I want to draw a line for the equation x+y=0 on the same scatter plot.
This is how the final plot should look like.
[image]

What I have now is this.
[image]

How to add the line x+y=0 to this scatter plot?

Comment: please do share what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-20,20)
```

you can simply do:

```
plt.plot(x, -x)
```

or, more generically:

```
def f(x):
    return -x

plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plot multiple stuff if you have not executed `plt.show()`.

If you have not assigned a variable as the figure, anything you plot will be saved to an invisible blank sheet and shown when you decide to.

```
x = np.random.randint(1,100,10)
y = np.random.randint(1,100,10)

xx = np.arange(1,100)
yy = -xx

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(xx,yy)

plt.show()
```

You can keep going until you decide to `show()`. The result here is:[image]